# How to call an MovieClip on stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

Trying to addChild() inside a movie clip in the stage from one of my classes. The code looks like this

```
package  {

import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class createFlask extends SimpleButton {

    public function createFlask() {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, createAFlask);
    }

    private function createAFlask(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var Flask = new flask  ;
        Flask.x = stage.width/2;
        Flask.y = stage.height/2;
        stage.experiment.addChild(Flask);
    }


}
```

This gives an error as

> Access of possibly undefined property experiment through a reference
>   with static type flash.display:Stage.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you define the variable `experiment`? Can you show the root Class?

Comment: experiment is a instance name of a movieclip in the stage

Comment: It is not on the stage. It is on the main timeline. You should use root instead, never stage.

Comment: I tried that, but still gives this error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property experiment through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: From where do you call this class (Simplebutton)?

Comment: this class is assigned to another movie clip in the stage

Answer (score -1):

Just omit "stage".
Instead use

```
experiment.addChild(Flask);
```

That will work.

Comment: Don't think it is going to work, experiment is not in OP's class.

Comment: yes, doens't work, it says **Access of undefined property experiment**

Comment: how to call a movie clip in the stage? stage.experiment does't seem to work, but calling experiment doesn't work at all